# Possible to call "command codes" from LaTeX?

Tags: tex-core

I'm reading through [tex.web](http://get-software.net/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web):

```
@ Next are the ordinary run-of-the-mill command codes.  Codes that are
|min_internal| or more represent internal quantities that might be
expanded by `\.{\\the}'.

@d char_num=16 {character specified numerically ( \.{\\char} )}
...
```

... and I would actually like to call this one:

```
@d remove_item=25 {nullify last item ( \.{\\unpenalty},
  \.{\\unkern}, \.{\\unskip} )}
```

Is it possible to somehow call these "ordinary" "command codes" from LaTeX -  and how might they be "expanded by \the"?

---

Edit: to clarify: above I see a "command" called `remove_item` which has some sort of a code of `25`. Is it possible to call this command from LaTeX - maybe through `\catcode25` (which doesn't work) or something similar (I'm speculating here: say, something like `\cmd:remove_item`)?

I don't understand the source code of Tex - but the way I read the above, there is an internal command `remove_item` in TeX, which apparently calls `\unpenalty \unkern \unskip`. I was hoping there is a way to call this `remove_item` from Latex...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but perhaps the answer is `\unpenalty` and `\the\lastpenalty`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @DavidCarlisle - I tried to clarify through an edit above, please let me know if I should clarify further. Cheers!

Comment: Oh so in that case the answer is simpler "no" :-)

Comment: Many thanks for that, @DavidCarlisle - would you mind posting that comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general there is no automatic mapping between internal functions of the web sources and functionality exposed as TeX primitives, so the answer to your question is essentially "no". You can do `\the\lastpenalty` and `\unpenalty` but that isn't quite what you were after.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming that, @DavidCarlisle - given I lack a lot of the TeX background, I have allowed (in this case) the code comments to slightly mislead me; which is why it's great to have an explicit answer to this documented. Cheers!