# Debugging vertical space on top of page (section inside a custom biblatex cite command)?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment, debugging

Please consider the following MWE, compiled with `lualatex test.tex` (+ `bibtex test` + `lualatex test.tex`):

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


% note: here the behavior is the same, 
% regardless if \thefield{title} (expandable)
% or \printfield{title} (non-expandable) is used:
%
\newbibmacro*{myCite}{%
\section*{The title: \thefield{title}} %
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myCite}%
{}%
{%
\usebibmacro{myCite}}%
{}%
{}%

\def\tracingboxes{\showboxbreadth = \maxdimen
  \showboxdepth = \maxdimen}%


\begin{document}

\tracingpages=1 % pages
\tracingoutput=1 % boxes
\tracingboxes

\section*{Thesting one}

\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage

\myCite{vangennep}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

In it, I have a directly called `\section*` on top of the page - and a `\section*` on top of the page called via a custom cite command (`\myCite`, implemented through `biblatex` package functionality). (Both sections start with "Th", so I have a marker for debugging)

The problem is that the two `\section*`s do not "align" - that is, do not start at the same vertical position (<sub>image produced via 
  `montage -density 150 -bordercolor LimeGreen -border 1 test.pdf[0] test.pdf[2] -geometry +2+2 -tile 2x1 out.png`</sub>):

[image: out.png]

In other words, the `\section*` called via `\myCite` has some extra vertical space on top of page. And since (apparently) one cannot just [reset the page vertical space on top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61077/reset-page-vertical-space-on-top) (especially not by [calling internal “command codes”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61595/possible-to-call-command-codes-from-latex)) - I'd like to know:

- where does this vertical space come from; and
- how to eliminate it?

In particular, I'm interested in somehow tracking down (through a "debugging procedure") where does this space come from.

I have already tried to get a "debug log" using [\tracing commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60491/latex-tracing-commands-list), in this case `\tracingpages`, `\tracingoutput` and `\tracingboxes`. Then I use the following `awk` command (*see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303580/grep-composite-statements-with-separate-context/)*) to search through the log:

```
$ awk '
{nrp=sprintf("[%5d]",NR);}
NR<=p {print nrp " :" $0} /^%%/ {print nrp "::" $0; p=NR+4} ;
/\\hbox|\\vbox|\\glue| box/ {print nrp "  " $0} ;
/\\OT1\/cmr\/bx\/n\/14.4 [Th]/ {print nrp "  " $0}
' test.log

[  283]::%% goal height=598.0, max depth=5.0
[  284] :% t=0.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[  285] :% t=43.90276 plus 1.86108 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[  286] :% t=55.90276 plus 1.86108 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[  287] :% t=67.90276 plus 1.86108 g=598.0 b=10000 p=100 c=100000#

[  298]  Completed box being shipped out [1]

[  299]  \vbox(676.36243+0.0)x373.0, direction TLT
[  302]  .\glue 23.0
[  303]  .\vbox(653.36243+0.0)x345.0, shifted 28.0, direction TLT
[  305]  ..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 5.55556fil, direction TLT
[  309]  ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[  310]  ...\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 340.0fil, direction TLT
[  313]  ....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[  317]  ..\glue 18.06749
[  320]  ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
[**321]  ..\vbox(598.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 434.09723fil, direction TLT
[**332]  ...\glue(\topskip) 0.00002
[**333]  ...\hbox(9.99998+2.79999)x345.0, glue set 253.16011fil, direction TLT
[  340]  ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
[  343]  .....\glue 0.0
[  344]  ....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 T
[  345]  ....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 h
...
[ 1703]::%% goal height=598.0, max depth=5.0
[ 1704] :% t=0.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[ 1705] :% t=10.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=-10001 c=-10001#
[ 1706] :%% goal height=598.0, max depth=5.0
[ 1706]::%% goal height=598.0, max depth=5.0
[ 1707] :% t=0.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[ 1708] :% t=10.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[ 1709] :% t=10.0 plus 1.0fil g=598.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[ 1710] :

[ 1712]  Completed box being shipped out [2]

[ 1713]  \vbox(676.36243+0.0)x424.0, direction TLT
[ 1716]  .\glue 23.0
[ 1717]  .\vbox(653.36243+0.0)x345.0, shifted 79.0, direction TLT
[ 1719]  ..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 5.55556fil, direction TLT
[ 1723]  ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[ 1724]  ...\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 340.0fil, direction TLT
[ 1728]  ....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[ 1731]  ..\glue 18.06749
[ 1734]  ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
[ 1735]  ..\vbox(598.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set 588.0fil, direction TLT
[ 1740]  ...\glue(\topskip) 10.0
[ 1741]  ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
[ 1745]  ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[ 1748]  ...\glue 0.0
[ 1751]  ..\glue(\baselineskip) 25.29494
[ 1752]  ..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
...
[ 1756]::%% goal height=598.0, max depth=5.0
[ 1757] :% t=10.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
[ 1758] :% t=64.97215 plus 7.16663 minus 0.86108 g=598.0 b=10000 p=150 c=100000#
[ 1759] :% t=76.97215 plus 7.16663 minus 0.86108 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
[ 1760] :% t=88.97215 plus 7.16663 minus 0.86108 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#

[ 1769]  Completed box being shipped out [3]

[ 1770]  \vbox(676.36243+0.0)x373.0, direction TLT
[ 1773]  .\glue 23.0
[ 1774]  .\vbox(653.36243+0.0)x345.0, shifted 28.0, direction TLT
[ 1776]  ..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 5.55556fil, direction TLT
[ 1780]  ...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[ 1781]  ...\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 340.0fil, direction TLT
[ 1784]  ....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[ 1788]  ..\glue 18.06749
[ 1791]  ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
[*1792]  ..\vbox(598.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 459.0834fil, direction TLT
[*1796]  ...\glue(\topskip) 10.0
[*1797]  ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 330.0fil, direction TLT
[*1804]  ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
[*1809]  ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
[*1811]  ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
[*1816]  ...\glue 15.0694 plus 4.30554 minus 0.86108
[*1819]  ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
[*1822]  ...\glue(\baselineskip) 8.00002
[*1823]  ...\hbox(9.99998+2.79999)x345.0, glue set 132.72354fil, direction TLT
[ 1830]  ....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
[ 1833]  .....\glue 0.0
[ 1834]  ....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 T
[ 1835]  ....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 h
```

I've isolated relevant sections of the log above - and the lines that differ in the box construction, right before the first "Th" letters of each `\section*` start being typeset, are indicated with `*` before the line number (<sub>for that, I removed the leading line numbers, and compared the two snippets with `meld`</sub>).

The [`\tracingpages` log](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60213/2595) (as much as I can read it) tells me that:

- pg 1 starts at top 0.0, penalty 0 (`% t=0.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#`)
- pg 3 starts at top 10.0, penalty -300 (`% t=10.0 g=598.0 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#`)

... yet, the `\tracingboxes` log shows that, in spite of this, the initial hierarchy of output boxes is the same for both cases, until this point is reached:

- pg 1: `..\vbox(598.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 434.09723fil, direction TLT`
- pg 3: `..\vbox(598.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 459.0834fil, direction TLT`

... and I cannot see how the top difference of 10.0-0.0 = 10.0 in the first case, would add up to 459.0834-434.09723 = 24.9862 (ignoring the fact that pg3 has additional boxes and glues) ??

In essence, it is clear that it is something in the path of the custom `biblatex` citation command that causes this vertical space on top - but how could the page/box building log be used, to find the exact command which is causing this? Or is a different debugging approach needed altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracing here is best done at the macro level: I'd load the [`trace`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/trace) package and use `\traceon`/`\traceoff`. If you load the trace package and do

\traceon
  \myCite{vangennep}

the start of the (rather long) long is

```
\myCite ->\blx@citecmdinit \@ifstar {\blx@citepunct {\blxcitecmd {myCite*}}} {\
blx@citepunct {\blxcitecmd {myCite}}}

\blx@citecmdinit ->\blx@leavevmode@cite \iftoggle {blx@bibliography} {} {\blx@i
nitunit }

\blx@leavevmode@cite ->\ifhmode \ifnum \spacefactor =\blx@sf@par \else \spacefa
ctor \@m \fi \else \leavevmode \fi 
{\ifhmode}
{false}

\leavevmode ->\unhbox \voidb@x
```

thus showing that citations are horizontal mode commands. That's where the issue is, as `\section` and similar expect to start new paragraphs. You'll see the same spacing issue as the example with

```
\leavevmode
\section*{foo}
```

as again we have an 'empty' paragraph followed by a section.

I'd say the solution here is to create a simple `\myCite` definition using `\newcommand`, as it's not a 'normal' citation at all as far as `biblatex` is concerned.

Comment: Thanks a million for this answer, @JosephWright - I must admit, I have tried the `\traceon`, have even suspected the `\leavevmode`, but was lacking crucial piece of info: "_horizontal mode commands... (vs.) `\section` and similar expect to start new paragraphs_" Thus, I thought I could confirm through an intermediate way - just by tracing the pages' construction. But it turns out, without the awareness of what `\leavevmode \section*{foo}` does, I could have hardly gotten any further. Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addendum: here is how the modified MWE looks, where a `\myCiteNcmd` command has been implemented via `\newcommand`, as per [@JosephWright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62029/2595):

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{trace}


\newbibmacro*{myCite}{%
\section*{The title: \printfield{title}} %
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myCite}%
{}%
{%
\usebibmacro{myCite}}%
{}%
{}%


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myCiteNcmd}[1]{%
  \def\blx@loopcode{\usebibmacro{myCite}} %
  \def\blx@precode{} % also needed
  \def\blx@postcode{\blx@postpunct} % also needed
  \def\blx@dlimcode{} % also needed, but only for multiple (comma-sep) "cites"
  \blx@blxinit % also needed (inits \printfield)
  \blx@citeloop{#1} %
}
\makeatother


\def\tracingboxes{\showboxbreadth = \maxdimen
  \showboxdepth = \maxdimen}%


\begin{document}

\tracingpages=1 % pages
\tracingoutput=1 % boxes
\tracingboxes

\section*{Thesting one}

\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage


\traceon
% \myCite{vangennep}   % the "old" command - biblatex custom cite
\myCiteNcmd{vangennep} % \newcommand
\traceoff

% note: multiple "citations" will pass OK,
% however, there is a new \section* added for each "citation"!
% \myCiteNcmd{vangennep,knuth:ct}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The above finally shows both `\sections*` being aligned all the same at the top of the page (and it works by calling the same `\usebibmacro` as previously, and even when it uses the unexpandable `\printfield` command from `biblatex`).

Note that here one needs to be careful to pass the citation entry keys to the `\biblatex` formatter - as most of the "front end" `\biblatex` command do *not*, in fact, use them (given that there is implied looping in `\DeclareCiteCommand`).

So, what I did was simply to observe the `\traceon` debug log (for the custom `biblatex` `\myCite`), and find that it is essentially executed via:

```
...
\blx@citei@myCite #1#2#3#4->\ifblank {#1} {} {\def \abx@field@prenote {#1}}\ifb
lank {#2} {\let \blx@thenotecheck \relax } {\def \abx@field@postnote {#2}}\def
\blx@precode {}\def \blx@loopcode {\usebibmacro {myCite}}\def \blx@dlimcode {}    def \blx@postcode {#4}\blx@citeloop {#3}\endgroup
#1<-
#2<-
#3<-vangennep
#4<-\blx@postpunct
...
```

Here it is obvious that the entry key is handled by `\blx@citeloop`. So, I copied all relevant stanzas from here into `\myCiteNcmd` - and beyond that, only needed `\blx@blxinit` to define `\printfield` itself.

Hope this helps someone - cheers!